# List to Dictionary without Values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I transform a list:

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6', 'd7', 'd8', 'd9', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5', 'e6', 'e7', 'e8', 'e9', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'g1', 'g2', 'g3', 'g4', 'g5', 'g6', 'g7', 'g8', 'g9', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'h7', 'h8', 'h9', 'i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4', 'i5', 'i6', 'i7', 'i8', 'i9']
```

into a dictionary with NO values:

```
{'a1': None, 'a2': None, 'a3': None} #etc
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a `dict` and not a `set`?

Comment: Just a nit, but 0 is not 'NO value', it's zero, which is arguably different. In Python, `None` us usually used to indicate 'No value'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
dict.fromkeys(yourlist, 0)

>>> l = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', ...
>>> dict.fromkeys(l, 0)
{'a1': 0, 'a2': 0, 'a3': 0, 'a4': 0, ...
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Docstring:
dict.fromkeys(S[,v]) -> New dict with keys from S and values equal to v.
v defaults to None.
```

---

```
In [1]: l = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']

In [2]: dict.fromkeys(l)
Out[2]: {'a1': None, 'a2': None, 'a3': None, 'a4': None}

In [3]: dict.fromkeys(l, 0)
Out[3]: {'a1': 0, 'a2': 0, 'a3': 0, 'a4': 0}
```

---

As pointed out by *DSM* in the comments, you have to be careful with setting mutable objects as values, as they all point to the same object. Change one, change all:

```
In [5]: d = dict.fromkeys(l,[])

In [6]: [id(v) for v in d.values()]
Out[6]: [171439660, 171439660, 171439660, 171439660]

In [7]: d['a1'].append(1)

In [8]: d
Out[8]: {'a1': [1], 'a2': [1], 'a3': [1], 'a4': [1]}
```

Comment: One thing to beware of when using `.fromkeys()` is that it doesn't make copies of `v`, so `len(set(map(id, dict.fromkeys(l, v).values()))) == 1`.  That's fine when `v` is immutable, such as here with either `0` or `None`, but can lead to surprises otherwise -- `dict.fromkeys(l, [])` is unlikely to be what's wanted, for example.  (I know you know this, root, but for passers-by. :^)

Comment: @DSM -- Added it to my answer, with an illustrative example. Thanks.

Comment: +1. Next time I have to explain multiple references to mutable objects I'm wipping out `[id(v) for v in d.values()]`. Nicely put.

Answer (score 4):

`my_dict = {elem:0 for elem in my_list}`

Ex:

```
In [2]: my_list = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']

In [3]: my_dict = {elem:0 for elem in my_list}

In [4]: my_dict
Out[4]: {'a1': 0, 'a2': 0, 'a3': 0, 'a4': 0}
```

Comment: So much for PEP 20: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: TIL about `dict.fromkeys`. Cool.